# Rewriterule (.htaccess) to redirect subdomains to subfolders

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting

I'm trying to automatically redirect a large number of subdomains to subfolders. Here's what I'm trying to do:

http://gerard.joling.easybookings.nl/ --> http://www.easybookings.nl/gerard-joling/

I'd like to replace dots in subdomains with dashed in subfolders. I currently have this regular expression/rewriterule:

```
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-z]+)\.([a-z]+)\.easybookings\.nl$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.easybookings.nl/artiesten/$1\-$2 [R=301,L]
```

This rewriterule returns "www.easybookings.nl/artiest/-".

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `%1` and `%2` back references here:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-z]+)\.([a-z]+)\.(easybookings\.nl)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%3/%1-%2/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-z]+)\.([a-z]+)\.([a-z]+)\.(easybookings\.nl)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%4/%1-%2-%3/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: That works for two terms in the subdomain. Is there a way to automate it for one ore more terms in the subdomain? I'm looking for a piece of code that works for: one.two.easybookings.nl --> www.easybookings.nl/one-two, but also for one.two.three.easybookings.nl --> www.easybookings.nl/one-two-three

Comment: As you can I have already provided you 2 rules to cover both cases.

Comment: So you have to provide different rules for both? I've got URL's variating from 2 to 10 terms in the subdomain. Any idear if it is possible to cover it with one rule?